# Error in : shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript file: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, r, shinyjs

I am trying to call my javascript code using my R code but I am encountering this error. 
**"Error in : shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript file: ReferenceError: require is not defined. "**

I have seen that the reason is

"This is because require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript."
[Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

I am really not familiar with client-side and server-side. I just need the javascript functions I created which calls a specific modules. Any idea how to do it?

In **ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(script="js/getAppDetails.js"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("analyze_reviews", label="Analyze", "js$getAppDetails('app_id')"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)
```

In **server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$app_selection, {
    invalidateLater(0, session)
    output$app_id <- renderText({
      app_detail$appId[1]
    })
  })

  observeEvent(output$app_id, {
    js$getAppDetails('app_id')
  })
})
```

In **getAppDetails.js**

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv').Parser
var fs = require('fs')
var json = require('json')

shinyjs.getAppDetails = function getAppDetails (appId) {
  // call some function to return data
    const detailJson2csvParser = new json2csv({appFields})
    const z = detailJson2csvParser.parse(data)
    let app_detail = z.substring(z.search(/\n/), z.length)
    fs.appendFile('AppDetail.csv', app_detail, function(status) {
      if (status) throw status
        console.log(`App Data of ${appId} successfully saved.`)
    })
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log('There was an error fetching the app data!')
  })
}
```

I am getting this error:
`Warning: Error in : shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript file: ReferenceError: require is not defined.`